# Visual Studio 2017 csproj - dotnet pack ProjectReference as exact version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

I am trying to get dotnet pack to generate exact version references when creating NuGet packages.  Let's say I have the following class hierarchy:

api.csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\api.types\api.types.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
```

api.types.csproj has no other dependencies and is simply used for the wire objects.

I have a custom process that updates the Version in all my csproj files prior to restore and build.  When I run dotnet pack I would like to be able to control the dependency in api.nupkg such that api.types is an exact version reference.  Is there an out of the box way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?